# How do I deduct payments to others out of a single payment to the group for contract work?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, income-tax

Another person and myself did contract work.  The company sent the entire payment for the work to me and I paid the other person out of that money.

How do I report this on my taxes?  I received the proper form from the company for the full payment, but how do I deduct the payment out to the other person?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You send the proper form to the other person for the amount you gave him, and file it as your business expense on your Schedule C.

Comment: This is not through a business.  We were paid as individual contractors.  I just happened to be the one the check was issued to and I sent the other person his half.   Does that make a difference?

Comment: @PaulPeterson that was what I was referring to. As a sole proprietor ("individual contractor") you're supposed to file your business related income and expanses on Schedule C of the form 1040.